# How do I find the source code to a table in pgadmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a simple question. When you create a table/query from Pgadmin, how do you find the source code ( not sure if these  are the correct words) you used?

I have looked under schema and can't find anything.

Attached is a photo.  Thank you

[image]

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/231952/is-there-an-equivalent-of-mysqls-show-create-table-in-postgres

Answer (score 2):

Select the object on the left tree view and go to the SQL tab on the right to see the DDL.